# Cypress get object return after click

Tags: cypress

i am doing some test on nuxt using cypress, i want to check my return object after register, the print in data work well but i cant never get the data out, isit possible that cypress check console.log return object and use it as a prove on the test ?

my intention is to use the return response status 201(create) and use as expect.

```
describe('Testing Register to backend', () => {
    const dummyUsername = 'Mxaabyxxcxxtxisxxsxx1suxsaxxx'
    const dummyEmail = 'Micxaebuxcxuxxxitxxssasx1sxx@gmail.com'
    const dummyPassword = 'aabjxlyucxxixxtassss21xx34x'

    beforeEach(function() {
        cy.visit('my-account') // we run our custom command
    })


    it('Should able get through register and return 200', () => {
        cy.get('.ps-tab-li #toggle__Register').click({
            force: true
        })
        cy.get('.form-group #register__tab--username').type(dummyUsername, {
            force: true
        });
        cy.get('.form-group #register__tab--email').type(dummyEmail, {
            force: true
        });
        cy.get('.form-group #register__tab--password').type(dummyPassword, {
            force: true
        });
        cy.get('button').contains('Register').click().wait(3000).then((response) => {
            // console.log()
            cy.log(response)
            // isit possible to get object data on log to use in expect ?

            //  HTTP 201 Created success status response code
            // expect(xhr.status).to.eq(201)
        })
    })

})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up an intercept on the URL where data is posted.

Roughly,

```js
cy.intercept('POST', url).as('post')  // set this up at top

// fill in form...

cy.get('button').contains('Register').click()  // trigger POST to url

cy.wait('@post')          // wait for intercept instead of cy.wait(3000)
  .then(interception => {
    // read the response
    expect(interception.response.status).to.eq(201)
  })
```

---

**One-off wildcard**

If you have trouble catching the URL after click, add an intercept that catches anything, and set it to only catch one response (the next one).

```js
// set this up at top of test
cy.intercept('POST', '*', { times: 1 })  // 'POST, '*' means any URL
  .as('post')                            // times:1 means catch once only
                                         // then turn off

// fill in form...

cy.get('button').contains('Register').click()  // trigger POST 

cy.wait('@post')          // wait for intercept 
  .then(interception => {
    // read the response
    expect(interception.response.status).to.eq(201)
  })
```

**Explanation**

The URL parameter of `cy.intercept()` command is a filter on requests coming from the app. When you add wildcards it catches more requests, for example `**/api/*` is a standard pattern that catches any API request.

If you have trouble catching a particular URL, you can use `*` which just catches everything.

But `cy.intercept()` remains active for all tests, so if we add `{times: 1}` then it will only apply to the next request and then stop catching requests. So it will catch the request from the button click, but not interfere with any other tests you add later that also require an intercept.

I suggest this should be a temporary step to help figure out what URL needs to be caught. Take a look at the properties of the interception request to figure out a better URL to filter by

```js
.then(interception => {
  console.log(interception.request)   // take a look at request URL property 
                                      // in devtools
  ...
```

Comment: ahh no mate, i active it but the response seem like not return anything.

Comment: Oh yes, I assumed something different.

Comment: the return is on the console.log, isit possible we got grab that to use ?

Comment: You can spy on console.log() but it's more trouble than needed. Find the URL posted to from Network tab in devtools.

Comment: well the problem i have is this register is using a plugins and it need key and id to bypass it also here

Error:
Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: post. No request ever occurred

Comment: Yeah that error means you don't have the right URL for the `cy.intercept()`. You can do a one-off wildcard - I'll add the code for that.

Comment: Hello @TesterDick it worked ! thanks you but some question on the code, if i set '*' it will automatic target the url i use to send to backend ? i know it represent all but it will set what i was using send to backend url right ? also why setting up times: 1 will work and not more ? could explain that part.